# Is possible to let angular handle some routes and mvc others?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, routes, ngroute

So I am working on an existing MVC app and a few days ago we added an angular module. We tried to load it with ajax, but angular refuses to load, so we decided to add angular route and a ng-view on index. The problem is that only the angular routes are working, the MVC routes are dead. Do I need to add them one by one to `$routeProvider` that would cause tons of unnecessary work? Also we try with 2 for testing and when the c# controller return a `View()` it wouldn't load in the specific ng-view div just load the partial as a full page.

This is my actual route config:

```
$routeProvider
      .when('/', {
          templateUrl: '/ServiceDesk/starter'
      })
          //Facturas
      .when('/app/Facturacion/MantenimientoFacturas', {
          templateUrl: '/Facturacion/MantenimientoFacturas',
          controller: 'FacturasController'
      })
          // Ordenes
          .when('/app/Facturacion/MantenimientoOrdenes', {
              templateUrl: '/Facturacion/MantenimientoOrdenes',
              controller: 'OrderController'
          });

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

I would love angular just to manage this routes and all the others be managed by MVC, is that possible or what the better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since routes are given priority depending on order, you just have to be smart as to what order your routes are in your MVC routes. As an example, it looks like

```
/app/Facturacion/
```

is where you want Angular to run. So in your MVC routes, add as your first route in RouteConfig

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ngRoute",
    url: "app/Facturacion/{*angularRoute}",
    defaults: new {controller = "Facturacion", action = "Index" }
);
```

So now anytime you hit a route starting with app/Facturacion/, angular routes will take over. Otherwise it will skip and continue using MVC routes. If there is a specific MVC route using the same path as angular (/app/Facturacion/), add it above the ngRoute in your RouteConfig and this will continue to run MVC and not angular.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "myMvcRoute",
    url: "app/Facturacion/someRoute",
    defaults: new {controller = "Facturacion", action = "SomeAction" }
);
```

Make sure in your FacturacionController that the Index action returns the View, and in your View, add your angular scripts and angular code. An example view would be something like

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Facturacion";
}
@section head{
   <base href="/"> //Add a head section in your layout (make it optional)
}
@section scripts{
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angularjs")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/facturacionSPA")
}
<div ng-app="facturacionApp">
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

And you Angular routes would look something like

```
  $routeProvider.when('/app/Facturacion/MantenimientoFacturas', {
    templateUrl: '/Facturacion/MantenimientoFacturas',
    controller: 'FacturasController'
  }).when('/app/Facturacion/MantenimientoOrdenes', {
    templateUrl: '/Facturacion/MantenimientoOrdenes',
    controller: 'OrderController'
  }).otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/ServiceDesk/starter',
  });
```

Also, angular templates should be regular html files, not partial views. Better to stick to angular for angular stuff and MVC for mvc stuff, don't mix them in my opinion!

EDIT:
If '/ServiceDesk/starter' is an mvc route and you don't want angular to route to it, you can do something like this in your angular controller:

```
if ($location.url().indexOf('/ServiceDesk/starter') >= 0 && supports_history_api()) $window.location.href = '/ServiceDesk/starter';
```

Code for supports_history_api() for completeness, this determines whether I use html5 mode for the $locationProvider as I need old IE to work

```
function supports_history_api() {
  return !!(window.history && history.pushState);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I got this doubt if i map this route : routes.MapRoute(
    name: "myMvcRoute",
    url: "app/Facturacion/someRoute",
    defaults: new {controller = "Facturacion", action = "SomeAction" }
);  in MVC but not in $routeProvider the app never hit the url; it will only redirect me to .otherwise even if i remove .otherwise it will redirect me to base href, it looks like i am force to add every route on $routeProvider am i right ?

Comment: yes, the angular app would never hit that url, I was stating that if you wanted to run a normal mvc url and not run the angular app. But i you wanted to load that url from within angular to get out of angular back to mvc, use $window.location.href, don't use angular $location (what I do anyway). So to go from angular to mvc, use $window.location.href=yourMVCroute. To stay within angular, use $location.